# React Native fetch request is not woriking on Android device

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios, fetch

I know this has been an issue for some time now but I have tried everything on the internet and nothing works.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:null in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I saw that the most mentioned solution was this **android:usesCleartextTraffic = true**, but that was already okay due to this notice I found on the react-native documentation and  after I cheked the Manifest file, property was set true.

```
On Android, as of API Level 28, clear text traffic is also blocked by default. This behaviour can be overridden by setting android:usesCleartextTraffic in the app manifest file.
```

Request:

```
  async upload(data: FormData): Promise<ITest> {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/test/file`, {
      body: data,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
    return response.json().then(res => res);
  },
```

Comment: Please share the code block where you are making the request/promise.

Comment: Just added the part that was missing @ShashankMalviya

Comment: Couple of notes on style: don't mix `await` and `.then` in the same function. Don't have Promises that can fail that don't have a `.catch` handler or are `await`ed in a try/catch. Your data is a `FormData` but your content type is set to 'application/json'? That's wrong, and may well be part of your problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah I understand that but this how backend requires it. Also this solution works perfectly on IOS. This is only happenning on Android

Comment: The backend *requires* data to be sent with the wrong content-type header? I kinda don't believe you but if true fire your backend coders. But seriously, try fixing that and see if the error goes away. If it does then the answer to your question becomes political rather than technical.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion but it did not work....

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or real device?

Comment: @ShashankMalviya I am testing on a real device